# What is difference from Reverse DNS Lookup - Reverse IP Lookup

Tags: dns, ip, reverse-dns

When using websites that retrieve *all|* domain names associated to an IP address, What is the difference between Reverse DNS Lookup and Reverse IP Lookup?

These two procedures show different outputs.
The reverse dns lookup is based from PTR records dns, generally show less result than ip lookup. But not ever the PTR record are present.

---

[EDIT]

DNS REVERSE LOOKUP (74.208.56.223):

```
223.56.208.74.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer perfora.net.
```

IP REVERSE LOOKUP (74.208.56.223):

```
andrewslist.org 2016-03-05
awppwlocal5.org 2016-03-05
belgerado.com   2016-02-01
blet301.com 2016-03-11
camasbiz.com    2016-02-01
camassmokeshop.com  2016-02-01
canhazcode.com  2016-02-01
capturedmemoriesbyjb.com    2016-02-01
creativemediatechniques.com 2012-11-12
culturalimmersions.com  2012-11-12
easywifihotspot.com 2012-11-12
emeraldtree-inc.com 2016-02-01
epharma360.com  2016-02-01
erosionguardproducts.com    2016-02-01
execusummit-registration.com    2016-02-01
fatboyzsports.com   2016-02-01
firedistrict23.com  2016-02-01
hawkeyebars.com 2012-11-12
historybooksource.com   2016-02-01
hr-execusummit.com  2016-02-01
illuminatingeyes.com    2012-06-29
insidescooponrealestate.com 2012-11-12
inst-for-ip.org 2015-04-03
kylehalloutdoors.biz    2016-03-05
kylehalloutdoors.com    2015-11-14
kylehalloutdoors.info   2016-03-08
kylehalloutdoors.net    2016-03-01
kylehalloutdoors.org    2016-03-05
kylehalloutdoors.us 2016-03-08
lakesidebrewer.com  2015-11-14
lakesidebrewingco.com   2015-11-14
letters2home.com    2015-11-14
litgationsymposium.com  2015-11-14
noraparksgroup.info 2016-03-08
northslopewriters.com   2015-11-14
occursillo.org  2016-02-26
pawlek.com  2015-11-14
pinedecline.com 2015-11-14
pinggemporium.com   2015-11-14
riafunda.com    2015-11-14
savvysoccer.com 2015-11-14
schavonephotography.com 2015-11-14
schiavonephotography.com    2015-11-14
shadesofsoul.info   2015-10-20
shorelinecomputerservices.com   2015-11-14
sirclesaver.com 2012-06-29
specializedsafetytraining.com   2015-11-14
specializedsafetytraining.net   2016-03-01
swaramanthra.com    2015-03-23
teachbytech.org 2016-02-26
tofinocoffeecompany.com 2012-11-12
w3colors.com    2015-11-14
```

Why the info obtained from reverse ip lookup are not present in DNS records? How to obtain this info the ip reverse lookup if them not present in DNS records?
With input an ip address I want in output all hosts associated with it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the distinction is that you're making between Reverse DNS and reverse IP can you give examples?

Comment: Added in post an example.

Comment: You're getting the second from a search engine query (of some sort)

Comment: these outputs were generated from viewdns.info

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

A reverse DNS look up is a very simple query against the DNS system.

A reverse IP look up is a very complex search database that has recorded the IP addresses of websites it has crawled. The result being a list of websites hosted at that IP address. This is impossible via DNS.

### A little more detail...

The DNS PTR record lookup is the record associated to that domain by the owner of the IP address. This is typically used by mail servers to confirm the identity of a server sending email to make sure it is authorised for that domain. Hosting companies will often have the reverse entry as the Machine or load balancer name.

What you can't get from DNS is a list of A records for a given IP Address. DNS lookups are purely one way. (hence the unusual format of the in-addr.arpa record)

To get around this, and to provide a service to people who are interested in that information, you can collect this information from search data, or by simply crawling the A records, or purchasing the DNS data from the domain registrars.

Once you have that data you will have list of *most* websites hosted by that server. It is probably impossible to get all records, simply because of the size of the DNS dataset there are going to be holes in any method of search and there is no way to query a server for what sites it is hosting. (or believes it is hosting)